Spring integration Hazelcast-based partitioned message flow during Hazelcast partition migration
I'm trying to implement a dynamic Spring Integration Router that changes its dynamicChannels based on the members in a Hazelcast cluster. I'm doing this to achieve partitioned distribution of messages. I use Hazelcast's partition tables to decide on the partition (and thus the member) which will need to handle a specific Message (based on a key in the Message). I use Hazelcast's MembershipListener to dynamically add/remove MessageChannels. The implementation of the router:
@Slf4j
public class ExampleRouter extends AbstractMessageRouter implements HazelcastInstanceAware, MembershipListener, MigrationAwareService {

    private PartitionService partitionService;
    private final CommandPartitionKeyResolver commandPartitionKeyResolver;
    private final RemoteRegistrationFactory remoteRegistrationFactory;
    private final MessageChannel localMessageChannel;
    private final Map<UUID, IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration> remoteRegistrationMappings = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public ExampleRouter(CommandPartitionKeyResolver commandPartitionKeyResolver, RemoteRegistrationFactory remoteRegistrationFactory, MessageChannel localMessageChannel) {
        this.commandPartitionKeyResolver = commandPartitionKeyResolver;
        this.remoteRegistrationFactory = remoteRegistrationFactory;
        this.localMessageChannel = localMessageChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        this.partitionService = hazelcastInstance.getPartitionService();
    }

    @Override
    public Operation prepareReplicationOperation(PartitionReplicationEvent event) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeMigration(PartitionMigrationEvent event) {
        // TODO: 'Hold' all messages from now on (taking into account concurrency)
    }

    @Override
    public void commitMigration(PartitionMigrationEvent event) {
        // TODO: 'Release' all messages
    }

    @Override
    public void rollbackMigration(PartitionMigrationEvent event) {
        // TODO: 'Release' all messages
    }

    @Override
    public void memberAdded(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
        Member member = membershipEvent.getMember();
        UUID memberId = member.getUuid();
        var registration = this.remoteRegistrationMappings.get(memberId);
        if (registration != null) {
            log.warn("Member {} already registered", memberId);
        } else {
            if (!member.localMember()) {
                registration = createRemoteRegistration(member);
                this.remoteRegistrationMappings.put(memberId, registration);
                log.info("Registered remote registration {} for member {}", registration.getId(), memberId);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void memberRemoved(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
        Member member = membershipEvent.getMember();
        UUID memberId = member.getUuid();
        var registration = this.remoteRegistrationMappings.remove(memberId);
        registration.destroy();
        log.info("Destroyed remote registration {} for member {}", registration.getId(), memberId);
    }

    private IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration createRemoteRegistration(Member member) {
        String destination = member.getAttribute(HazelcastConfig.DESTINATION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        return this.remoteRegistrationFactory.create(destination);
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
        Object payload = message.getPayload();
        if (payload instanceof Command command) {
            return resolve(command);
        } else {
            log.error("Received unsupported {}. Message not routed.", message);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    private Collection<MessageChannel> resolve(Command command) {
        String key = this.commandPartitionKeyResolver.resolve(command);
        Partition partition = this.partitionService.getPartition(key);
        Member owner = partition.getOwner();
        if (owner == null) {
            HazelcastPartitionOwnerNotEstablishedException exception = new HazelcastPartitionOwnerNotEstablishedException(partition);
            log.warn("Owner of " + partition + " unknown", exception);
            throw exception;
        } else {
            MessageChannel resolvedMessageChannel;
            if (owner.localMember()) {
                resolvedMessageChannel = this.localMessageChannel;
            } else {
                var registration = this.remoteRegistrationMappings.get(owner.getUuid());
                if (registration == null) {
                    HazelcastRemoteRegistrationUnavailableException exception = new HazelcastRemoteRegistrationUnavailableException(owner);
                    log.warn("Registration for " + owner + " unknown", exception);
                    throw exception;
                } else {
                    resolvedMessageChannel = registration.getInputChannel();
                }
            }
            log.debug("Resolved {} for key {}", resolvedMessageChannel, key);
            return Collections.singletonList(resolvedMessageChannel);
        }
    }
}

The challenge I face is implementing the code that will 'hold' incoming messages while Hazelcast partition migrations occur. I don't want to risk messages getting routed to the wrong member because a Message was routed to a MessageChannel based on an old Hazelcast partition table. Only when a partition migration is completed, routing should resume.
I think I can use Hazelcast's MigrationAwareService SPI to receive callbacks when migrations start and end. However I don't now how to 'hold' the messages coming into the router until the migration is complete (taking into account the concurrent nature of Hazelcast partition migrations and messages coming into the router). I feel like a router is not the correct integration component to 'hold' messages in any way.
Any help is appreciated.

Sounds like a Thread Barrier is the one that you can try to block the flow until migration is done: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/barrier.html. You probably can use a simple router upfront against some boolean to determine if migration has been started, so you would hand your message to that barrier until migration is complete to trigger that barrier to release the message.
See also Hazelcast chapter in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/hazelcast.html. Might some of the out-of-the-box components can help you with Spring Integration style of configuration.
UPDATE
Pseudo diagram of the possible flow:
router_to_check_migration_in_progress (or filter) ->
false -> go to the normal logic, like your router based on the channel according to the member
true -> go to the barrier
barrier waits for the migration complete event via its trigger action
barrier's output goes to your normal logic, e.g. the router for the channel based on the current member.
The barrier in this case is like a detour and does its stuff only when migration is in progress.
The router (or filter) in the beginning might be based on some global AtomicBoolean bean which is switched on when Hazelcast migration has started and off when it is complete.
Filter might be easier in this case because it is really based on the predicate logic for true/false and its discardChannel does the trick to route the message to the barrier.

I'm not sure how that would prevent the router from routing anymore messages since the barrier gets the message after it already went through the router. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your explanation. Could you provide a psuedo integrationflow how that would look?

See an UPDATE in my answer.
